# Cannot scroll unless I set a width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll

My WPF application displays a timeline as a UserControl and as such, uses a scrollviewer.

The width of the UserControl depends on certain values and so could be 0 pixels wide to N wide.

The problem I have is getting WPF to know how wide this is.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TimeLineCanvas.UserControls.TimeLine"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:TimeLineCanvas.Helpers"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=Window}}">
<Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="300" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="450"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
        <Grid>
            <!--<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500">-->

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="110" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvasMarkers" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" /> <!-- this will always be the widest of the canvas's-->

            <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvasShowEvents" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />

            <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvasFailEvents" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <!-- I doubt anything below this is useful for this post but I keep it in case I'm wrong-->

    <Grid x:Name="ConfigurationGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" >

        <StackPanel>
            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Zoom" />
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Content>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource LightBorder}">
                        <StackPanel>

                            <TextBlock Text="Select Zoom Out Level" />
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ScaleFactorOptions}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                   
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              SelectionChanged="ZoomLevel_SelectionChanged"
              >
                                <ComboBox.Resources>
                                    <helper:ZoomConverter x:Key="ZoomConverter" />
                                </ComboBox.Resources>
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ZoomConverter}}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>

            <Expander IsExpanded="True" >
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Time Period" />
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Content>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource LightBorder}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Change Time Period" />
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodOptions}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPeriod, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                   
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              SelectionChanged="TimePeriod_SelectionChanged"
              >
                            </ComboBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>

            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Properties" />
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Content>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource LightBorder}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtProperty"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

As you can see in my code above, I've commented out a line where I set the width to 500. When I do this, the scrollbar appears and I can scroll along for that value which may or may not coincide with the width of my canvas.

I also tried adding a `ColumnDefintion = Auto` just to see if this would help, it didn't.

Do I have to work out how wide the Canvas is in the code behind and then manually set the width or can XAML do this automatically for me by using the `Stretch` within a `HoriztonalAlignment` property (or similar)?

Comment: This does not seem right to me.  The width of the UserControl depends on certain values and so could be 0 pixels wide to N wide.  But you hard code column widths in the user control (450,300).  That user control IS 650 pixels wide.

Answer (score 0):

As it is right now, you have all controls auto sizing to fit their content, which kind of defeats the purpose of a `ScrollViewer`. Instead, get rid of the `Grid` and set `HorizontalAlignment` on the `ScrollViewer` to `Stretch` (or manually assign it a size).

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help. I actually need the grid as there are other controls in there (removed to keep code consice) but to test it, I removed all controls and the grid, added the HorizontalAlignment and sadly, no change

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the width property of the grid to the width property of the canvas

For example in the grid:

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=youcanvas, Path=Width}"
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to bind, that isn't the question! The question is, can it be done with the XAML!

Comment: @DaveRook That sure looks like XAML to me.

Comment: I have updated my question, I can now see why my question wasn't clear. Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="450"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10">
            <Grid>
                <!--<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500">-->

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="110" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvasMarkers" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" />
                <!-- this will always be the widest of the canvas's-->

                <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvasShowEvents" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />

                <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvasFailEvents" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- I doubt anything below this is useful for this post but I keep it in case I'm wrong-->

        <Grid x:Name="ConfigurationGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">

            <StackPanel>
                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Zoom" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Expander.Content>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource LightBorder}">
                            <StackPanel>

                                <TextBlock Text="Select Zoom Out Level" />
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ScaleFactorOptions}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScaleFactor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          SelectionChanged="ZoomLevel_SelectionChanged">
                                    <ComboBox.Resources>
                                        <helper:ZoomConverter x:Key="ZoomConverter" />
                                    </ComboBox.Resources>
                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ZoomConverter}}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>

                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Time Period" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Expander.Content>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource LightBorder}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Change Time Period" />
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodOptions}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPeriod, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          SelectionChanged="TimePeriod_SelectionChanged">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>

                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="Properties" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Expander.Content>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource LightBorder}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtProperty" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Like Adam said, your controls are auto size so it doesn't know what is the "MaxWidth" that the ScrollViewer should scroll to that's why it is disabled.

Update 1: Since you have more controls outside, you want ScrollViewer outside so that it defines the entire scrolling area. It is the Grid who is dictating the inner scroll viewer's scrolling area and its auto size so it doesn't know. Wrapping a ScrollViewer outside will know its overall scrolling area so that ScrollViewer inside will also behave as you expected.

Comment: Leo, this gives me the scroll bar, but, the value is not correct. I can scroll a tiny % of the total width needed.

Comment: Add the Width binding to the Grid too and remove it from the Canvas. Sorry I didn't test it.

Comment: Same as just binding to the ScrollViewer... I get the feeling the fault could be else where and I may have to try and work it out manually in the code and then bind it!#

Comment: No, I experienced what you your problem is. I didn't have to work it out manually in the code. I believe this has something to do with your outer grid because you mentioned something about it.

Comment: Updated my answer. Problem lies on the outer one.

Comment: Last question, why you don't want to explicitly set the Width of the Grid inside? You explicitly set the Width of the ColumnDefinition to 450. Why don't you set it to 450 too? Then you can get rid of the ScrollViewer outside.

Comment: Sorry Leo, I copied and pasted what you had, still no scroll bar! Thank you so much for your efforts, sadly I have to leave now as I promised to take children out for dinner but will be back tonight or tomorrow (UK)

Comment: Leo, I do want that. And even if I do that, the issue is, it still only scrolls by a few %. With my test data, I literally have to make the width about 10000 for the scroll bar to show and scroll the full width... I need to do this manually I think

Comment: The issue with 10000 width for the scroll to show is because its probably just maxing out the width of the scroll area. It doesn't scroll to me by a few %. Have you tried it with the ScrollViewer outside and setting the Grid width to 450 too?

Comment: Leo, the issue is due to the [Canvas as it doesn't resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670133/is-there-a-way-to-automagically-make-a-canvas-scroll-on-overflow-in-wpf)