# ScrollViewer Focus Error in WPF in Code behind

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

To create a circle below each time the button is clicked. In canvas

position of Circle move to out of canvas.

But, Scroll viewer does not move up and down.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scv" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="135,0,0,0" Focusable="True">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="373" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="685" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Is there a way to move up and down the scroll Viewer?

edit

An attempt was made to try to use the code to the link to me the site, an error occurs

don't use code... Anything simple way?

Comment: Here's your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/670141/3596441

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automagically make a canvas scroll on overflow in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670133/is-there-a-way-to-automagically-make-a-canvas-scroll-on-overflow-in-wpf)